How to Integrating Monaco Editor with Vite + Vue3 project
I don't konw how to edit my 'vite.config.ts' to Integrating Monaco Editor. I need you help, thanks!
I have used the vite-plugin-monaco-editor plugin before, and it can run, but this plugin hasn't been updated for a long time. I'm hesitant to use it and prefer to use the official method. However, I don't understand the official doc.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

put this code in your main.ts file:
import editorWorker from 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.worker?worker'
import jsonWorker from 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/json/json.worker?worker'
import cssWorker from 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/css/css.worker?worker'
import htmlWorker from 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/html/html.worker?worker'
import tsWorker from 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/typescript/ts.worker?worker'

self.MonacoEnvironment = {
  getWorker(_, label) {
    if (label === 'json') {
      return new jsonWorker()
    }
    if (label === 'css' || label === 'scss' || label === 'less') {
      return new cssWorker()
    }
    if (label === 'html' || label === 'handlebars' || label === 'razor') {
      return new htmlWorker()
    }
    if (label === 'typescript' || label === 'javascript') {
      return new tsWorker()
    }
    return new editorWorker()
  }
}

and in your component for example:
const el = ref<HTMLElement>();

onMounted(() => {
  editor.value = monaco.editor.create(el.value, {
    value: "html text",
    theme: "vs-dark",
    language: "html",
    dimension: {
      height: 800,
      width:800,
    },
  });
});

